# Transparent plastic effect with glowing

Tags: modeling, materials, shader-nodes

I have a simple cube that I'm trying to make into a transparent glowing cube similar to this real cube below.

[image]

I'm having a hard time to get the look right. First I'm testing it to a simple cube with a solidity modify on it, then array it into a grid of a 3x3 and bevel the edges. I copied this material node because it's the best I've found for making it glow right when the lights are out, but when the lights are on, and it's not supposed to be glowing it looks solid.

I will work on making the cube pieces more accurately, but for what I'm doing with the version I have made now, I am trying to make the transparent green added to the node setup I made from the glowing node setup below from the link.

https://blenderartists.org/t/glow-in-the-dark-plastic-material/629434

The plastic is transparent enough to see the dark parts under the faces of the pieces. I'll make that later, but I'm going to fake it till I make it for now. This image below is another cube in a different color that has no stickers, so you can see what is visible with the lights on.

[image]

My model:
[image: Glowing cube]
[image: Not Glowing and not transparent]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe duplicate your cube mesh in order to create a plastic layer. As for the colored material, plug the image into the Emssion as well to get something a bit phosphorescent:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the image you're using? I'm only curious because I'm not using any images, so I'm not sure what that is supposed to be.

Comment: I've just drawn a green and black image